# I want to use JDK8 on macOS slave of Jenkins macOS but node is failing builds when removing earlier JDK

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, java-8, java-11

Sorry this question might be similar to any other but those questions did not solve my issue.
I had JDK 11 [primary] and JDK 8 [secondary] installed for Jenkins slave agent due to requirement.
Then JDK 11 started giving JNLP connection error after builds are successful but build status is FAILED.

Now I want to use JDK8 [as primary JDK] on my macOS slave to avoid JNLP connection error as my Master Jenkins is having JDK8.

But as soon I remove JDK11 , all my projects on that particular MacOS node fails before starting with error :-

check out build error logs when I removed JDK11 :-

> 

```html
FATAL: Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 192.xx.xx.50/192.xx.xx.50:49xxx
  at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1737)
  at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:313)
  at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:952)
  at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:1052)
  at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
  at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
  at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
  at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
  at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
  at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh" (in directory "Jenkins_home/workspace/java11-failure-on-mac-test"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
 at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1299)
 at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1259)
 at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
 at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
 at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
 at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Help would be appreciated..!

Comment: Please include the logs as text, inside your question, not as a linked picture.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I edited it, can you help with this problem.